# Android AppCompat 22.1 text in EditText of an AlertDialog cannot be copied

Tags: android, android-support-library, contextual-action-bar, android-appcompat

As title, when I use AppCompat 22.1, with the AlertDialog in the appcompat, when having an EditText inside the dialog and the text is selected, the "copy" and "paste" buttons(the contextual actionbar) is laid under the dialog instead of overlaying and the buttons cannot be touched by the user(showed in the picture below). How can I fix this? Thanks.

[image: Picture of contextual actionbar laying below dialog]

EDIT:
the theme style related to this question is as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.DarkBase" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/pink_a400 </item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.indigoDark" parent="@style/Theme.DarkBase">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/indigo_500</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigo_700</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/indigo_a400</item>

</style>
```

Comment: What happens when you set, `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` to `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>`

Comment: I've tried it, and nothing happens...

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. Looks like a fix will be released "soon". https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170105